# How to scrape a website's "Inspect Element" HTML source code with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Using python 2.7, I'm figuring out how to scrape multiple websites. I want to find out if specific keywords exits within website's source code or not. Up until recently, I tried this by scraping the website's source code found by using Chrome's **"View-source"** function (right clicked on a page).

However, to accurately find the specific keywords, I've learned that it's required to use Selenium (unfamiliar to me) to scrape a website's HTML source code **found by using Chrome's Inspect Element tool**. For a lack of better term I'll simply call this the: **"Inspect Element"-source code** of a website.

With my current script, I've made a start by figured out how to crawl the **"View-source"-code** of websites to extract desired keywords like `@media` and `googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js`. By crawling this **"View-source"-code**, I thus realised that I won't accurately find the desired keywords here and that it's much more reliable and accurate to scrape a website's  **"Inspect Element"-source code** instead!

My script:

```
import urllib2
import csv

fieldnames = ['Website', '@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']

def csv_writerheader(path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()

def csv_writer(dictdata, path):
    with open(path, 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(dictdata)

csv_output_file = 'EXPORT_Results!.csv'
# LIST OF KEY WORDS (TITLE CASE TO MATCH FIELD NAMES)
keywords = ['@media', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', 'googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js']

csv_writerheader(csv_output_file)

with open('top1m-edited.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, lineterminator='\n')
    for line in f:
        strdomain = line.strip()
        # INITIALIZE DICT
        data = {'Website': strdomain}

        if '.nl' in strdomain:
            try:
                req = urllib2.Request(strdomain.strip())
                response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                html_content = response.read()

                # ITERATE THROUGH EACH KEY AND UPDATE DICT
                for searchstring in keywords:
                    if searchstring.lower() in str(html_content).lower():
                        print (strdomain, searchstring, 'found')
                        data[searchstring] = 'found'
                    else:
                        print (strdomain, searchstring, 'not found')
                        data[searchstring] = 'not found'

                # CALL METHOD PASSING DICT AND OUTPUT FILE
                csv_writer(data, csv_output_file)

            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                print (strdomain, 'HTTP ERROR')

            except urllib2.URLError:
                print (strdomain, 'URL ERROR')

            except urllib2.socket.error:
                print (strdomain, 'SOCKET ERROR')

            except urllib2.ssl.CertificateError:
                print (strdomain, 'SSL Certificate ERROR')

f.close()
```

So by using python 2.7, how do I scrape a website's **"Inspect Element"-source code** using Selenium (preferably using my current script for the most part)?

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup` if you want to navigate the pages html

Comment: The View source and Inspect Element source are the same, except if you render the HTML with a browser, the Javascript'll have rendered the HTML and converted it. Once you render the page with selenium grab the HTML content and use BeautifulSoup to parse it out.